# What's wrong with this url?

Tags: html, url, xul, xulrunner, malformed

Why is Xul app saying

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

for:

```
    <browser class="AppBar" type="content" src="test.html?img1=img1.jpg&img2=img2.jpg" flex="4"/>
```

at the equals sign of `&img2=img2.jpg"`?

Note that it works without the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ampersand `&`..

The xml escape is generally `&amp;`

```
<browser class="AppBar" type="content" src="test.html?img1=img1.jpg&amp;img2=img2.jpg" flex="4"/>
```

Comment: Got it.. By the way, how's that way using [CODE] keyword to scape code? do you know?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Hi, just to register here, I was talking about <![CDATA[ notation on the previous comment.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change & to `&amp;`

You also have to do [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for

```
' -> &apos;
< -> &lt;
> -> &gt;
" -> &quot;
```